# Could someone check my PayPal Smart Button?

Tags: button, paypal

I'd be grateful if some kind person would glance over this PayPal SmartButton code?
I've put in the NO_SHIPPING and I'm not sure about all the brackets (){}[] and whether there should be double " or single ' inverted commas etc.
I'm OK with html, but this scripting mystifies me.
Thanks in anticipation, Steve

```
    <div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&e nablefunding=venmo&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-        factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'buynow',
          
      },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{"description":"item for sale\nacceptM/accept43_BB1frT6.htm","amount":{"currency_code":"GBP","value":20}}],
          
        application_context: {
           shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
        }

        });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            
            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

           //actions.redirect('https://www.website.com/');
            
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

Comment: Images of text are not acceptable, use three backticks ``` to enclose code

Comment: Anyway, it looks like you need a comma between the purchase_units array and the application_context object. It's standard JavaScript/JSON

Comment: Thank you Preston, I will re-post the edit:
purchase_units: [{"description":"item for sale\nacceptM/accept43_BB1frT6.htm","amount":{"currency_code":"GBP","value":20}}],
          
  application_context: {

Answer (score 0):

Script SDK line is not correct, has extra spacing and a missing hyphen. You need:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
```

That's simply the code the button factory would have generated for you, and it works.

For future reference most HTML/JS problems can be troubleshooted in a browser's Developer Tools, on the Console and Network and (for HTML) Inspect tabs, reloading the page once the Network tab is open for example.